# Keep select list choice after refresh

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have the following code that redirects the page (onchange) based on the value of option's choice.
For example we are in index.php. There is a select list and if the user chooses Design that has value "one" the redirected page will be the same page but with different url ( index.php&one )

My goal is to have the selected option, selected after the redirection/refresh.

**Here is my code**

```
<select size="1" name="Products"
onchange="if(this.options.selectedIndex>0) window.location.href = 'index.php&'+this.options [this.options.selectedIndex].value">
<option value="">Please Select a Product</option>
<option value="one">Design
Software</option>
<option value="two">Manufacturing
Software</option>
<option value="three">Machine Tools</option>
</select>
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: you can send/fetch the param w/ `$_GET` e.g. `index.php&selected=one` and fetch w/ php `$_GET['selected']` and then set the appropriate option w/ the `value="one"`

Comment: You probably want to replace that ampersand & with a question mark ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with javascript and jQuery framework:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var option = gup('option');
$("select option[value='"+option+"']").attr('selected','selected');
});

function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

Keep in mind that you have to change the  `&` to `?` and set a parameter and a value. like `option=one`.

So the corresponding javascript must change to this:

```
onchange="if(this.options.selectedIndex>0) window.location.href = 'index.php?=option'+this.options [this.options.selectedIndex].value">
```

**Demo:** http://lb.vg/969f6

Answer (score 0):

Store data in cookies on change and reload when page (or other page) is loaded

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass the variable along with the redirect. Then, get it out of the $_GET variable, and check to see if the value is set when building the select.

```
<?php
$menu_option = $_GET['product'];
?>
<select size="1" name="Products"
onchange="if(this.options.selectedIndex>0) window.location.href = 'index.php?product='+this.options [this.options.selectedIndex].value">
<option value="">Please Select a Product</option>
<option value="one"<?php if ('one' == $menu_option) { echo ' selected="selected"; } ?>>Design
Software</option>
<option value="two"<?php if ('two' == $menu_option) { echo ' selected="selected"; } ?>>Manufacturing
Software</option>
<option value="three"<?php if ('three' == $menu_option) { echo ' selected="selected"; } ?>>Machine Tools</option>
</select>
```

Comment: $menu_option = $_GET['product']; will give you warning if $_GET['product'] is not set.

Comment: Gaurav is correct, I was just giving a basic solution, not necessarily production code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$selected = 0; 
if(isset($_GET['Products']))
   $selected = $_GET['Products'];

?>

<select size="1" name="Products"
onchange="if(this.options.selectedIndex>0) window.location.href = 'index.php?Products='+this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].value">
<option value="">Please Select a Product</option>
<option value="one" <?php echo ('one' == $selected) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?> >Design
Software</option>
<option value="two" <?php echo ('two' == $selected) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>>Manufacturing
Software</option>
<option value="three" <?php echo ('three' == $selected) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>>Machine Tools</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/paulschreiber/misc/blob/master/php/popup_menu.php

I have a function that handles this. The version on github's a bit old, but should still work.

```
$productList = array (
"one" => "Design Software"
"two" => "Manufacturing Software"
"three" => "Machine Tools"
);

$js = "onchange=\"if(this.options.selectedIndex>0) window.location.href = 'index.php?Products='+this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].value\"";

print popup_menu("Products", $productList, $js);
```

Answer (score 0):

replace onchange with this one:
onchange="if(this.options.selectedIndex>0) window.location.href = 'index.php?pro='+this.options [this.options.selectedIndex].value">