# php: Keep select option after submit

Tags: php, mysql, forms, submit-button

I have a type of grocery list where I want to able to add items from different stores.

Currently I have a form where I post the article number and quantity and then press submit to add the item to the grocery list (the table below).

```
<form action="<?php echo $current_file.$id; ?>" method="POST">

    Store:  <select>
                    <option value="gross1">Store 1</option>
                    <option value="gross2">Store 2</option>
                    <option value="gross3">Store 3</option>
            </select>

    Art no: <input type="text" size="15" name="number"  /> 

    Quantity: <input type="text" size="3" name="q" />

    <input type="submit" value="Add item" />

</form>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Art no
        </th>
        <th>
            Article name
        </th>
        <th>
            Price
        </th>
        <th>
            Quantity
        </th>
        <th>
            Total
        </th>
    </tr>
```

The stores item lists are stored in mysql tables so I want to choose the store (or the table if you so will) via a drop down select list. But the problem is, if the store I'm choosing items from isn't store 1, its going to pretty frustrating to select the store over and over again after every time I press submit.

I don't think I can use a script that uses some kind of GET variable to specify the selected store, because I already use GET to specify the selected grocery list. Is there another way to get the site to remember the selected store after a page refresh?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can have multiple GET variables, i.e. `example.com?var1=hello&var2=goodbye`

Answer (score 0):

In your php you would normally set SELECTED against the option based on the POSTed value. But you need to set a name on the select tag.

Have you tried searching google for any of this?

Comment: Yes, I've googled it for a couple of days now, the only thing I found was this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233252/keep-select-list-choice-after-refresh but if I understand the code right, the script have to use GET. But maybe I'm wrong? :S

Comment: I just put "keep selected option after submit" and there are pages of advice, all similar to mine. After typing into Google you have to actually read the results. They all say similar to mine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and needed a quick solution.After selecting a value from the dropdown list and submitting, the page reloads which resets the dropdown list as was - without keeping the selected value (even though the selected value was sent ($_GET). For me the issue was purely aesthetic since I wanted the user to see the value they selected. Here is what I did:

```
// Change the parent dropdown selected value to the currently selected value
    $(window).load(function() {

        // Get url attributes which should contain the $_POST or $_GET value and split it. You have to refine this in case you have multiple attributes

        var str=window.location.href; var n=str.split("=");

         // This should be the selected value attribute
         var myAttrVal= n[1];

       // check all options and grab the value (or whatever other unique identifier you're using). Check this value against your url value and when they match, add the selected attribute to that option.
        $('#selectID option').each(function() {

            var selectedOptVal = $(this).attr('value');

            if ( myAttrVal  == selectedOptVal) {

                $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
            }
        });

    });
```

I'm sure there are much better ways of doing this but I hope it gives you ideas on how to solve your problem.